# MATLAB web command

Tags: matlab, user-interface, web

when I open a local HTML-file with the `web` command, it´s possible to execute MATLAB-commands within the browser, which will be executed in MATLAB. Is it possible to fire commands in the other direction? E.g. Execute a JS-method from MATLAB-code using the browser handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got all undocumented methods via `myBrowserObj.methods`:

```
myBrowserObj.executeScript('alert("test")')
```

enables, to execute JS-Code in the browser object. To prevent errors, wait until the page has been loaded before execute that command.